# Load a single .JSON model in A-frame

Tags: json, aframe

I'm trying to load a single .JSON model exporter from Blender to A-frame

I already try using this loader

https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders

but the model don't show up.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>  
        <script src="components/json-model.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a-scene>
            <a-assets> 
                <a-asset-item id="model" src="models/stockcar.json"></a-asset-item> 
            </a-assets>


        <a-entity json-model="src:#model" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"></a-entity>

        <a-camera position="0 0 20"></a-camera>

        <a-light type="point" color="#3d8be6" position="-10 0 0" look-at="#car" intensity="5"></a-light>
        <a-light type="hemisphere" color="#33b522" position="-10 0 0" intensity="1"></a-light>


        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is what the console is showing

```
A-Frame Version: 0.5.0 (Date 10-02-2017, Commit #110055d)
index.js:74three Version: ^0.83.0
index.js:75WebVR Polyfill Version: dmarcos/webvr-polyfill#a02a8089b
json-model.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
three.js:19590THREE.WebGLRenderer 83
http://127.0.0.1:57153/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `json-model.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`. Check your path, ensure you're running a local server, and that your file is a JSON file.

Comment: I'm sure my file is a .JSON because I already load it using three.js so everything supposed to be good with the file, about the server, I'm been running some other test with other formats like collada and obj and everything works fine

Comment: Check the network inspector to see what it's returnng.

Comment: @ngokevin Here's my scene already uploaded to a test server, maybe you could have a look and point me to the error.

http://www.pre.nacion.com/archivo/A-FrameJSONModel-loadingTest_19_1620027983.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have an extra "/" at the end of your asset-item opening tag :

```
<a-asset-item id="model" src="models/stockcar.json"/></a-asset-item>
```

Secondly, to use the asset you have to state the asset's id in the json-model "src" attribute:

```
<a-entity json-model="src:#model" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"></a-entity>
```

Comment: Thanks for your corrections, however the model still not showing : ( 
Already did the changes on the code above

Comment: Bummer... I was hoping that would do the trick! Do you have a link to your scene? the one above doesn't work for me...