# How to use three JS JSON models in A-frame

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, aframe

I want to use some low poly models from https://clara.io/ as a ThreeJS JSON model in A-frame. I want to use this because it is much more efficient and smaller than a 3D model, which will load much faster also. But there is no description of how to use it.

As I see there are some other people ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521409/load-a-single-json-model-in-a-frame),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930473/how-to-properly-load-a-json-file-in-threejs),[3](https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders),[4](https://clara.io/learn/user-guide/data_exchange/threejs_export)) who have trouble with that but no one suggested any good idea.

So do anybody has a good description or step-by-step guide, or something like that? I tried to use as a script, mentioned in the [official description](https://clara.io/learn/user-guide/data_exchange/threejs_export), but didn't worked:

```js
        <a-scene>
        </a-scene>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
                loader.load("globe.json",function ( obj ) {
                     document.getElementsByTagName('a-scene').add( obj );
                });
        </script>
```

Tried to use it with [object loader](https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras/blob/master/src/loaders/object-model.js), but I've got the dependency error `module is not defined`. So now I'm a bit confused about this,, how to use, or how to start using models in this way.
Any suggestion, any idea about this?

Comment: Any logs from the official description approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tldr: afaik JSON models are deprecated, and trying to make them work would mean creating a new loader from scratch.

I'm afraid the best solution is to:

- download blender
- download the model in a *.blend format
- open it up in blender
- export as glb
- load it up as a `gltf-model`.

---

non - tldr:

Trying to load up a `json` model via the `THREE.ObjectLoader`, it tries to use [JSONLegacyLoader](https://github.com/supermedium/three.js/blob/dev/src/loaders/ObjectLoader.js#L420-L428).

[To find it, you need to check out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53930452/2425787) threejs R110 before it was completely removed (loader [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r110/examples/js/loaders/deprecated/LegacyJSONLoader.js)).
After all, it needs the deprecated [Geometry](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r140/examples/js/deprecated/Geometry.js). 
When imported, something crashes in the rendering pipeline. Doesn't look like its worth the effort.

Tried with [this](https://clara.io/view/790976e3-f99c-4f34-b475-f83fa14693b8) model.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. It seems a much better way than a `gltf` model which is large and makes everything so slow in my simulation if I want to use a few models...  I'm sad that they stopped supporting the smarter way, but I also understand it. Nowadays everybody has the power to run large scenes in their browser even on their phone. At least we think, that everybody has...

Comment: Tried converting the car model into `glb` - it doesn't look any bigger than the JSON stuff. Maybe you mean complex sketchfab models?

Comment: I tried on [this globe](https://clara.io/view/9666279a-5be4-47f0-97c7-636b406272b5#) and the downloadable `JSON` (the old one) is only 1 kb zipped, the `glb` version is 382 kb... At this point, it is totally pointless to use it to stream it, or anything else. If I want to stream a full animation with complex models, or huge models such as chemical or geological models (I'm working on many projects...) then this makes it meaningless. It will be only a lagging unenjoyable mess. :( Also without a good internet connection will be very slow. This is so sad. Why do we go back if we have good things?

Comment: It's strange why the `deprecated json` one is around 1kb, and the `json` is 816kb. If you open up the deprecated JSON model, and search for `"type":"Geometry",`, all data is empty - no vertices, no normals, no faces - looks like the `deprecated json` is broken and unusable (since it's a scene with 2 empty geometries). So I'd compare the 816kb JSON to the 382kb glb.